# Will my program return the correct position I wanted after meeting a set number of newlines?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-18.04, low-level-io

I'm trying to read a file backwards (say 10 lines at the end of the file). I would increment my new line counter (`newline_counter`) everytime it reads a '\n'. Once `newline_counter` reaches `user_num` (argument), say 10 lines, `lseek()` would stop at the current position (`current_pos`). I'm returning this position so that I can use this position in another function which uses `lseek()` to this position and start reading from this position and write until the end of the file. I have successfully compiled the program but once I start to run it, the program just keeps running and there is no output.

```
int func_line_mode(int infile, int user_num) {
    char c;
    int newline_counter = 0;
    int current_pos = 0;
    int end = lseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);

    int counter = 0;

    while (counter < end || newline_counter <= user_num) {
        lseek(infile, current_pos, SEEK_END);
        read(infile, &c, sizeof(char));
        if (strcmp(&c,"\n") == 0) {
            newline_counter++;
        }
        current_pos--;
        counter++;
    }

    return current_pos;
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 Alright I changed it. But the program still does not output anything.

Comment: `&c` is **not** a pointer to a valid string so using `strcmp(&c,` is illegal.

Comment: What program? The above is a function with no output to the console.

Comment: shouldn't you use `while (counter < end && newline_counter <= user_num)` instead ? so, if one condition fails, the loop stops (and avoid something bad if `user_num` is greater than `end`

Comment: @Bathsheba it is in the other part of my code. I'm not showing that because I believe there's no problem there.

Comment: So how can we point out problems in code that you're not showing? We're good on this site but not **that** good. Perhaps the function loops rather than returns?

Comment: @Cid ahh yes thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your code:

1. The `while` condition is wrong, it should be:

   ```
   while (counter < end && newline_counter <= user_num)
   ```
2. After the `while`, you are left one byte before the last newline, so you should go forward 2 bytes to be precise:

   ```
   if (current_pos < 0)
       current_pos += 2;
   ```
3. `lseek()` returns an `off_t`, not `int`, so you should do:

   ```
   off_t end = lseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
   ```
4. As a consequence, other variables that you use to do comparisons should be `off_t` too, and most importantly the return type of the function too.
5. `strcmp(&c,"\n")` is wrong, to compare a single character you can just do `c == '\n'`.

Number 1 is probably the reason of your problem. Other points should be fixed too, specially number 4.

---

Once all of the above is fixed, the function correctly works for me. Here's a working example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

off_t func_line_mode(int infile, int user_num) {
    char c;
    int newline_counter = 0;
    off_t current_pos = 0;
    off_t end = lseek(infile, 0, SEEK_END);
    off_t counter = 0;

    while (counter < end && newline_counter < user_num) {
        lseek(infile, current_pos, SEEK_END);
        read(infile, &c, 1);

        if (c == '\n')
            newline_counter++;

        current_pos--;
        counter++;
    }

    if (current_pos < 0)
        current_pos += 2;

    return current_pos;
}

int main() {
    char buf[100];
    int nread, nwrite;

    int fd = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);

    // Last 3 lines.
    off_t off = func_line_mode(fd, 3);

    printf("off = %d\n", off);

    // Go back.
    lseek(fd, off, SEEK_END);

    while (nread = read(fd, buf, 100)) {
        nwrite = 0;

        while (nwrite < nread)
            nwrite += write(1, buf + nwrite, nread - nwrite);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the working example Mr.Bonelli, but do you mind explaining the while loop? I don't understand that.

Comment: @JingTan which one, the one in my `main()`?

Comment: Ah yes the one in main(), sorry for not specifying.

Comment: It's just a standard way to read until the end of a file and write all to standard output. `read()` does not guarantee to read *all* the 100 bytes, so I do `nread = read(...)` to know exactly how many were read. In the same way, `write()` does not guarantee to write *all* the `nread` bytes out, so I keep writing with a loop until I wrote all the `nread` bytes. When `read()` returns `0` (meaning end of file reached), the outer loop exits.

Comment: I just quickly wrote a working example, of course you should also check for errors when using `read()` and `write()`, which my code does not.

Comment: You're welcome. If this correctly answered your question, please accept it by clicking the green tick on the top left, so that this post can be marked as solved.